# Edit the admin/sales_order/index page

Tags: magento, admin

I want to add Total orders below the Orders heading in admin/sales/order page in the red box in the image. but I am unable to find that page. Can anyone help me to do that?[magento admin sales order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O5ih.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Header label is inserted by the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order class construct at app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order.php:40:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'sales_order';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Orders');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Create New Order');
        parent::__construct();
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/create')) {
            $this->_removeButton('add');
        }
    }

    public function getCreateUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_create/start');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the header but I need a view file for sales_order/view. Can you tell me where can I find that view file?

Comment: Solved. Appended the total orders as header text in above file. Thanks for your help.